# Clear options without clearing reference to them

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a variable containing the options of a select element:

```
var allOptions = document.getElementById('ddl').options;
```

When I am removing the options

```
var selector = document.getElementById('ddl');
selector.options.length = 0;
```

the options in `allOptions` are also removed.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: impossible to say what you are asking here

Comment: You need to clone the object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: No, it makes sense. He gets a _reference_ to `options` and later changes `options.length` from a seemingly different place... and he doesn't understand why...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**cloneNode**](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_clonenode.asp) to create an exact *copy* of the original `select` node. This way, you can safely clean the dropdown without affecting the variable that holds the original options:

```
var originalOptions = document.getElementById('ddl').cloneNode(true).options;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vvHzD/)**.